# After switching compiler in qt I'm getting error

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, compiler-errors

After switching default compiler in qt to gcc 4.6.2 I'm getting following error:

> **c:\ndk_buildrepos\qt-desktop\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp:93: error: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'**

With the compiler switch I also did two more things - I overwrote `mingw32make` with make from gcc 4.6.2. I did the same for the clean step.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Seems like you're missing a library or source file. You'll need to find out where  _Unwind_Resume is defined and include that in the linker process.

Answer (score 0):

_unwind_resume is part of the compiler runtime library - it deals with unwinding the stack when handling an exception.

This post http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/undefined-symbol-_unwind_resume-192813/ suggests linking with  the library gcc_s ( -lgcc_s )

Here's a similar solution: http://www.pgroup.com/userforum/viewtopic.php?t=1636&sid=a1f1e9e649686d97a21ba367284ea3ce

Here's someone with the same problem using QT: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33394-Link-errors-undefined-reference-to-_Unwind_Resume-and-__gxx_personality_v0 . They say "Running C:\Qt\2010.04\bin\qtenv.bat fixes the problem."